# How to decrypt the script in /WebResource.axd?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

My ASP.NET page contains the following javascript:

```
<script src="/WebResource.axd?d=15vmbg60zcHcSXzKfaF3EuqFn0fp5pwB8Nx5bGKsbYB3CuWkb0-zxykp1JN452LNQuyoGfkSoXUtzNpyRiQhNA65c1V5wCfL5A67dh_QGi01&amp;t=634776840793002537" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I didn't write this piece of script. So is there any way to decrypt it to show its logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can download it.

Just write the address in your browser like http(s)://.....whatever.com/WebResource.axd?d=15vmbg60zcHcSXzKfaF3EuqFn0fp5pwB8Nx5bGKsbYB3CuWkb0-zxykp1JN452LNQuyoGfkSoXUtzNpyRiQhNA65c1V5wCfL5A67dh_QGi01&t=634776840793002537

hit enter and you will be able to see the script or download it depending on your browser config.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Network` panel in `Developer Tools`, and find the required request of WebResource and see the `response`.